# Is it wrong to use a Java future for an infinite operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, clojure, future, java.util.concurrent

I need to implement an infinite operation in a Clojure program. I hope the syntax is reasonably clear for Java programmers too:

```
(defn- my-operation
    (future
        (while @continue
            (do things)
            (Thread/sleep polling-time)))
```

That gives me exactly what I want, the operation in a different thread so it does not block the main one, and also a pretty clear and straightforward syntax without having to deal with native Java functions which would force me to use the dot special form.

But the definition of a Java future is a "representation of the result of an asynchronous computation" and in this case, well, I'm not really doing anything with the result.

- Is it wrong to use them this way?.
- Is there any technical difference that should worry me compared to starting my own Thread?.
- Is this semantically wrong?.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve - in Java the future will return value once the computation is done. In your case you talk about infinite operation - as I understand it - this will never produce a result, so the Future will never complete... I think if you want to run some infinite computation - you just spawn a thread and run it there (take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will tie up a thread in the thread pool that Clojure manages, and uses for such things. The intended use of that thread pool is for short running operations, so it's kind-of a misuse. Also, the intention behind a `future` is to calculate a value once so it can be dereferenced multiple times, so that's kinds-of a misuse too.

There are lots of other options for long running tasks, including using Java's Executor framework, core-async or starting your own thread.

```
(defonce background-thread (doto (Thread. (fn []
                                            (while @continue
                                              (do things)
                                              (Thread/sleep polling-time))))
                             (.setDaemon true)
                             (.start)))
```

As others have mentioned, it might be worth thinking about unhandled exceptions. Stuart Sierra's blog post is a [great place to start](https://stuartsierra.com/2015/05/27/clojure-uncaught-exceptions).

The docstring for `future` says that it returns something you can call `deref` on. It is a reference type in the same way that `delay` or `atom` is, with it's own semantics of how it get's a value and while it's true you could just create a future and let it run forever, if you see a future in some code, it implies that you care about the value it produces.

```
(clojure.repl/doc future)
-------------------------
clojure.core/future
([& body])
Macro
  Takes a body of expressions and yields a future object that will
  invoke the body in another thread, and will cache the result and
  return it on all subsequent calls to deref/@. If the computation has
  not yet finished, calls to deref/@ will block, unless the variant of
  deref with timeout is used. See also - realized?.
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much. It does confirm the intuitions that I had and offers an alternative with a nicer syntax than the one I had in mind. Please, if you can point me to documentation where it explains that the future thread pool is intended for short running operations I would greatly appreciate. I would like to leave this decision documented.

Comment: This explanation is wrong. `future` is just the tool to reach for when you have some blocking or otherwise long-running task to do in the background; and you don’t have to be interested in the result. The number of threads here is unbounded. There is nothing wrong with `(future (regularly-log-stuff-or whatever info))`.

Comment: @glts There is the problem of exception swallowing, which happens if you never request a result. And why tie up a thread in a pool if you intend for that thread to be used for the length of the program? What would you gain by using a pool over just creating your own thread? If you have multiple tasks that may die and be restarted, sure, that saves creating threads. I can't see a one-time-use, long-running task benefiting from a pool.

Comment: It's an unbounded threadpool. Tying one up doesn't really cost anything.

Answer (score 2):

It should also be noted that `Future`s will swallow all exceptions that take place in them, *until* they're dereferenced. If you never plan on dereferencing them, be prepared for tears.

I've been bitten *multiple* times by this, where suddenly everything just stops working for no apparent reason. It's only later that I realize that an exception occurred that I had no idea about.

---

Along the same vein as what @l0st suggests, this is what I've been using for simple cases:

```
(defmacro thread [& body]
  `(doto (Thread. (fn [] ~@body)
         (.start))))
```

Everything you then pass to `thread` will be implicitly run in a new thread, which allows you to write:

```
(thread
  (while @continue
    (stuff)))
```

Which is basically what you had before in terms of syntax. Note though that of course this will shadow the macro with the same name if you ever decide to `use` Clojure.Async.

Ya, dealing with Java interop is a pain, but if you just tuck it away somewhere, it can lead to some nice custom code.

Comment: Nice addition and good example of the macro. The exceptions point as you said is extremely important. I've seen that too!.

Comment: You gain nothing with this macro. This is functionally equivalent to using `future` (slightly worse in fact, since you don’t get the benefits of the cached thread pool behind `future`).

Comment: @glts It's a readability helper obviously, nothing more. In my version, I actually type hint the function to prevent `lein check` warnings, since it's unable to infer that `fn` creates `Runnable`. It's just a way of tucking ugly bits away. Using a thread pool would also be detrimental for long running tasks, as mentioned above.

Comment: And I should note that "detrimental" was the wrong word to use. Tying up a thread in a pool just for the sake of using a pool however seems silly.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I’m interested in idiomatic Clojure. The point of my comment was that `future` is the built-in and idiomatic tool to put a piece of code in the background – whatever it is, no custom code necessary … So true, I don’t understand what is gained by using a dedicated thread instead of `future`, that’s all.

Comment: @glts Again, you'll be able to be alerted of exceptions by creating your own thread. The OP isn't using the thread to get a `future` result, they're using it to carry out side effects, so they won't (and can't) ever deref the future. Idiomatic code is great until it's harmful. Really, they should probably have stuff set up to use `async` so a long running thread isn't even necessary in the first place.

Comment: @glts To answer the question though of "should I run an unending task in a future?", I'd say no. Using a thread pool likely wouldn't benefit him here (except saving him a fraction of a second once), and the exception swallowing is killer. The fact that they chose to include exception swallowing heavily suggests that the intent is *not* to use futures to carry out side effects, which arguably makes your suggestion unidiomatic.