# Off-loading an HTTP Request w/o Leaking Threads

Tags: multithreading, clojure, future

I need to make an HTTP request which quite often can fail and I'm totally not interested in the result, if it worked or not. Also, I don't want to wait for it to return.

So, I'd like to wrap that call in a separate thread and make sure that the thread won't stick around when something is blocking.

My current approach is something like this:

```
(defn- call-and-forget [url]
  (let [timeout 250
        combined-timeout (* timeout 2.5)
        f (future
            (try
              (http/delete url
                           {:socket-timeout timeout
                            :conn-timeout   timeout})
              (catch Throwable e
                (printf "Could not call %s: %s"
                        url (.getMessage e)))))]
    (deref f combined-timeout)
    (when-not (future-done? f)
      (future-cancel f))))
```

*I hereby put this code under the Apache 2.0 license*

It uses [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) to make the call and a Future to create another thread. I am aware of this using a thread of the built-in pool and the discussion over in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744811/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-java-future-for-an-infinite-operation). The amount of complexity added by using my own thread pool, thread factory, executor service, uncaught handler and so on is not really worth it.

Would you agree that the code above is a good, working solution, or do you see a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. You could also do

```
(when (= :failed (deref f timeout-ms :failed))
  (future-cancel f))
```